# Error al compilar el programa. Error cs0168

Tags: c#

Hola cuando compilo un programa y lo ejecuto obtengo siempre el mismo error en Visual Studio. Aunque al final se ejecute el programa resulta bastante molesto.
Mensaje de error:

```
'Tanji.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tanji.vshost.exe): 'C:\Users\android\Desktop\c#\habbo\Tanji-master\Tanji\bin\Debug\Tanji.exe' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
'Tanji.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tanji.vshost.exe): 'C:\Users\android\Desktop\c#\habbo\Tanji-master\Tanji\bin\Debug\Eavesdrop.dll' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
'Tanji.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Tanji.vshost.exe): 'C:\Users\android\Desktop\c#\habbo\Tanji-master\Tanji\bin\Debug\Sulakore.dll' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
El subproceso 0xa88 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x190c terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El programa '[5288] Tanji.vshost.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

Si saben la solución pues de verdad que me vendría muy bien. Un saludo y hasta pronto.

Comment: Esto no te permite ejecutar tu programa?, ya que como comenta rnd es solo una advertencia.

Comment: por cierto, el mensaje de CS0168 no se ve en tu pregunta, te recomiendo editarla y agregar la salida del compilador para que otros puedan encontrar esta pregunta en el futuro.

Comment: ¿Hay código que puedas aportar? Hay muchas respuesta para el resultado que da el ejecutable.

Answer (score 2):

El código [CS0168](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf85t6e4.aspx) no es un código de error, es una advertencia.

Indica que has declarado una variable y no la has utilizado.

Ejemplo que daría esta advertencia:

```
public static void Main()
{
   int j = 0;      // CS0168, de comenta la siguiente linea
   // j++;
   ClaseX a;       // CS0168, en lugar de este, intenta el código de la siguiente linea.
   // ClaseX a = new ClaseX();
}
```

#### Solución:

Busca la linea de código que te indica el compilador y elimina esa variable, de todos modos no la estas utilizando.